# Dynamically call multiple chains

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, chain

Is there a way to call multiple chains dynamically?

I have an object
`var object = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value1', key3: 'value3' };`

and i have a method that can accept multiple chains `method().chain1( arg1 ).chain2( arg2 ).chain3( arg3 )...`

now i want to dynamically call the chain method, many times for the object properties, the keys of the object are the name of the method chains and the value its the arguments that i want to send into the chain.

My objective is calling this example underneath, in a `for` loop or in a function that makes this possible.

ex:

```
var object = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value1', key3: 'value3' };

var a = Object.keys( object )[0],
    b = Object.keys( object )[1],
    c = Object.keys( object )[2];

method[ a ]( object.key1 )[ b ]( object.key2 )[ c ](object.key3  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental flaw in your design, unless your chainable calls are order-independent: an object's properties do not have an inherent order (although in practice they do, it's undefined in the language).

But if you change your data structure a bit you can do this the right way:

```
var chain = [{f: 'key1', arg: 'value1'}, {f: 'key2', arg: 'value1'}, {f: 'key3', arg: 'value3'}]

function chainCall(chain)
{
    var obj = method
    for(var call of chain) {
        obj = obj[call.f](call.arg)
    }
    return obj
}
```